# Unsuccessful updates render :edit. Why is the edit from displayed at the :show path?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

A typical Rails update action looks something like this

```
def update
  respond_to do |format|
    if @object.update(object_params)
      # success results
    else
      format.html { render :edit }
    end
  end
end
```

I would therefore expect that, if update is not successful, the user will end up on path `/objects/:id/edit`.

Why then is the actual path `/objects/:id`, but with the edit form displayed?

Is this normal behavior, or something odd happening in this app?

### Edit

```
#routes.rb

devise_for :users
resources :objects do
  resources :children, only: [:index, :new, :create]
  member do
    get :customaction
  end
end

#ability.rb
can :create, Object
can :manage, Object, id: @user.object_id
cannot [:index, :destroy], Object
```

Comment: Could you show your routes?

Comment: thanks @borderline, added to the question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let me explain,

I hope you have noticed in the edit form its like

```
<form class="edit_post" id="edit_post_1" action="/posts/1" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post">
```

the form data is posted at `/posts/1`; this is the URL hit by the browser to     send the form data.

So when your `update` tasks fails or any `validation` error occurs; you do not redirect the http request rather render the `edit-form` and return to the browser. And the browser displays the form without changing the `web address`.

**Note**: only `redirect` changes the web address, `render` doesn't.

You assumption would be correct if the form data were submitted to `/posts/1/edit` rather than `/posts/1`